# How to install 230V Light with Light-activated-resistor?

Tags: electrical, lighting, safety, security

I am trying to set up light-activated-resistors that activate a light during dark hours. I have bought a ready Chinese thing that apparently contain a driver to change from AC to proper DC output for the light but I I don´t know for sure. The fact that the cords connected to the Chinese white light-activation thing are so thin hints me that connecting them directly to the 230V sockets is not probably the best idea. I have hacked an old radio power cord (on the picture) but I am afraid to plug it to the device before proper understanding of the system. The house where I am experimenting has no earthed sockets so I don´t know how to try out this kind of devices, not wanting to fire up the house.

So how can I install the device? What kind of precautions should I have? Where and how I should try the device? If I can understand right, it requires AC in.

[image]

**PCBs**

[image]

[image]

**Instructios in Chinese**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show a picture with all of the devices and the wires coming out of them? It's very hard to say looking at what you have.

Comment: @TimPost: the lamp is a attached to the point with 2 red wires (on the other side). The first picture have two activation device (with light-activation-resistors inside). The 230V black cable is not from the device, my old radio cord.

Comment: You can scan the document and use an online OCR service and then translate it in google translate (or use the android app for direct translation) - For sure one of the pair of wires goes to 220volt - It does not matter that they are thin. Then 22volt needs to go to the light fitting - that is switched by this board I suspect. Possibly ask for an english manual form the supplier.

Comment: I have always had really good customer experience with the Chinese. I would not be surprised if you contacted them via email or phone,  they would be happy to send you some English instructions.

Answer (score 1):

This leaflet just contains some general information concerning the product. The only thing relevant to installation is in point 5 (labeled 五).

Basically, the user is told to connect what are literally labeled as the "fire wire" and "null wire" (火线 and 零线) -which I interpret as respectively the red and the black wires- to an AC supply of 180 to 250V, 50 to 60Hz frequency, where the device should happily consume less than 60W of power.

This agrees quite well with what is on the bottom of the box.

This device does not need an earth connection, since the enclosure is plastic. Earthing is used when the container is metal, and the user could receive a shock if a live wire was touching the interior.

In addition, please note the timing seems to be able to be graduated, from 50 +/- 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're supposed to wire the photoresistor board into a low-voltage relay. This relay would switch AC power to the load (a light in your case).

I can't read the instructions, but they seem to have a 5-step installation process. If you posted a translation of those instructions, we might be able to interpret them appropriately.

Comment: If the OP had the translated instructions, I don't think they would have asked the question. They would have just read the instructions ;P

Comment: You should post much better pictures of the PCB, so that component markings can be read. It is impossible to identify that IC, for instance, from the picture you have posted.  Also, the copper-side of the PCB.  A shot of the component side without seeing the copper traces is useless for reverse engineering purposes.

Comment: @Kaz Good comment, but please leave it on the post rather than my answer. I'm not sure the asker will get pinged with it down here, and it makes more sense up there, anyway.

Comment: Not a 5-step installation process, just general information with some notes on installation in point #5 (labeled 五).

Answer (score -3):

It appears you the red and black wire simply hook up to the corresponding hot legs of a 220v circuit. The schematic from your last image does not require translation.

Its "good" to use caution, but your not going to tear the space time continuum. Plug it in to a  switched source that you can turn off fast and dont worry about it :D

Comment: Not a good idea unless you want to see some smoke.